# MySQL IN with LIKE

Tags: sql, mysql, select, where-clause

How would I use a IN table with like? So that I could use % in them? By in I mean:

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM table 
 WHERE age = "50" 
   AND name IN ("tim", "bob", "nancy", "john");
```

I already tried:

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM table 
 WHERE age = "50" 
   AND name LIKE ("2010-09-17%", "2010-09-16%")
```

But it gave the error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a number of LIKE expressions:

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM table 
  WHERE age = "50" 
        AND (
             name LIKE "2010-09-17%" 
             OR name LIKE "2010-09-16%"
            );
```

or you can use a regex:

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM table 
 WHERE age = "50" 
       AND name REGEXP "2010-09-17.*|2010-09-16.*";
```

or, cleverly

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM table 
 WHERE age = "50" 
       AND name REGEXP "2010-09-1(6|7).*";
```

Comment: While correct, I think you should make it explicit that you're pointing out that the OP *can't* do exactly what he's asking.

Comment: I expanded my answer, and added the REGEX option.

Comment: [REGEXP documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html): less efficient than LIKE.

Answer (score 7):

There is no combination of the LIKE and IN clauses.  It's either one, or the other, syntax:

```
SELECT fields
  FROM table
 WHERE age = 50
   AND (   name IN ('tim', 'bob', 'nancy', 'john')
        OR name LIKE '2010-09-17%'
        OR name LIKE '2010-09-16%')
```

The alternative to consider when searching text is [Full Text Search (FTS)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html):

```
SELECT fields
  FROM table
 WHERE age = 50
   AND MATCH(name) AGAINST('tim bob nancy john')
```

...but this requires MyISAM tables, and Full Text Indexing.

Comment: While this is more specific, the other one works in the way I wished.

Answer (score 2):

Put the values in a table (`MyParamsTable`) and use `LIKE` in a `JOIN` condition e.g. something like:

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM table 
       INNER JOIN MyParamsTable
          ON table.name LIKE CONCAT(MyParamsTable.name, "%")
 WHERE age = "50";
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it doesn't seem to work as described. I had to CONCAT(MyParamsTable.name,  "%") for it to work.