# Using 'LIKE' with an 'IN' clause full of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to do a soft string match in a table, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emailaddresses where addr in ('john@google.com', 'jim@google.com')
```

But if there is an addr value in the table 'JOHN@google.com', I want that returned.

Sort of like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emailaddresses where addr LIKE in ('john@google.com', 'jim@google.com')
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335359/is-it-possible-to-use-like-and-in-for-a-where-statment

Comment: All the addresses are formatted in a non-standard way - so just tolower-ing won't necessarily catch them all

Comment: For me this is a duplicate of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732246/mysql-in-with-like) but I'm sure *someone* would protest about it not being an exact duplicate because it namechecks MySQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

put the values into a table and use a `join` rather than an `in` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM emailaddresses as ea
INNER JOIN addresses as a
ON ea.address like '%' + a.address + '%'
```

Comment: If his database is actually case-sensitive, LIKE comparisions are still affected by collation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Comment: the concat syntax for my db is a double pipe, so the last line for me is `ON ea.address like '%' || a.address || '%'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [LOWER function](http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_function_upper_lower.php)

```
SELECT * FROM emailaddresses where LOWER(addr) in ('john@google.com', 'jim@google.com')
```

Which will convert all addr to lowercase, in which you can then compare the results to what you want.

Comment: +1, this will work for your needs.  If you truly need to use all `like` functionality I would recommend looking at my method.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `LIKE` will work either case-sensitively or case-insensitively depending upon which collation is in effect for the expression, but in your case, you have specified no wildcards so there is little point looking to use `LIKE`.

The default SQL Server installation is case-insensitive.

If you want a case-insensitive compare because you've got a case-sensitive database, [you can cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx).  I believe this is the appropriate syntax (I've never used it for an IN list on one side of an expression, though).

```
SELECT *
FROM emailaddresses
WHERE addr COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
IN (
    'john@google.com' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    ,'jim@google.com' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
```

A real case for `LIKE` would be something for something like `addr LIKE '%@google.com"`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the 'LIKE-In' approach together in SQL but in somewhat different style, like the one below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emailaddresses 
WHERE addr LIKE 'john@google.com' OR addr LIKE 'jim@google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a cross join to a table containing a list of email's you want to search for:

```
declare @email table(
email_check nvarchar(500) not null)

insert into @email(email_check)
values('jack@google.com')
insert into @email(email_check)
values('john.@google.com')



select hit, ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS from (
    select CHARINDEX(email_check, lower(EMAIL_ADDRESS)) hit, ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS
    from Table_With_Email_Addresses
    ,@email
) t
where hit > 0
```

No need for a "like" since it will parse a string to find a match.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from HotelAmenities_ 
where Pamenities in (
            select distinct(pamenities) 
            from HotelAmenities_ 
            where pamenities like '%Swimming%'
        )
```