# what is my implode problems?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I want to make form where user can search certain info based on their input and choices.after all the form filling the data will be display using table..got error with my implode where it gave me warning  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in line 111 which is

```
$check = implode("','", $_POST['check_list']);
```

and after that i tried tick two values on checkbox it gave me 
     mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 125 which is

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
```

.

```
      <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3><label for="usr">Carian bajet anda:</label></h3>
    <div class= "col-md-12">
    <div class=" col-md-4"></div> 

          <div class=" col-md-4">
          <input name="bajet" type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></div>

        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-4"></div>
        </div><br>

        <h3><label for="sel1">Pilih negeri pilihan anda:</label></h3>

        <div class= "col-md-12">
    <div class=" col-md-4"></div> 

          <div class=" col-md-4">
              <select class="form-control" name="sel">
                <option>Kuala Lumpur</option>
                <option>Negeri Sembilan</option>
                <option>Pahang</option>
                <option>Perak</option>
                <option>Terengganu</option>
                <option>Selangor</option>

              </select>
           </div>

           <div class=" col-md-4"></div>
        </div><br>


          <br>
          <h5><label for="check">Senarai Pra-perkahwinan:</label></h5>
       <center> <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox"name="check_list[]"  value="Jurufoto"><label>Jurufoto</label></label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox"name="check_list[]"  value="Butik"><label>Butik</label></label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox"name="check_list[]"  value="Hiburan"><label>Hiburan</label></label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox"name="check_list[]"  value="Kad Kahwin"><label>Kad Kahwin</label></label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox"name="check_list[]"  value="Katering"><label>Katering</label></label>
           <br>


        </center>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="search">Search&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button><br><br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>


    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Jenis</th>
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <th>Negeri</th>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Pakej</th>
                        <th>Harga</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $check = array();
             $budget = $_POST['bajet'];
             $select = $_POST['sel'];
               $check = implode("','", $_POST['check_list']);
                 $finalCheck = "'".$check."'";
                 $check = array();

           if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);

          $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * 
             FROM vendor 
                RIGHT JOIN item 
                  ON vendor.v_id=item.v_id
                    WHERE item.harga <= '%". $budget . "%' 
                      AND vendor.state = '%". $select ."%'
                        AND vendor.type IN ('%". $finalCheck ." %')" );
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
                <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['companyName'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['contact'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['harga'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['pakej'] ?></td>
                        <td><a href="index.php?v_id=<?php echo $row['v_id']?>">View Package</a></td>


                    </tr>

                    <?php }
                } 
                print_r($_POST['check_list'] );
                ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove single or double quotes from implode you have given both. $check = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);

Comment: first check the output of `var_dump($_POST['check_list']);` and show us and remove quotes in implode. `$check = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);`

Comment: nope still got error

Comment: @TamimiBrewster please show us the output of `var_dump($_POST['check_list']);`

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Butik" [1]=> string(10) "Kad Kahwin" }

Answer (score 2):

always debug your code by printing the value and check it for the desired output

Let amuse that your post value for check_list is

```
$_POST['check_list'] = ['Jurufoto','Hiburan'];
```

So according to your code
after imploding like this

```
$check = implode("','", $_POST['check_list']);

$finalCheck = "'".$check."'";
```

your $finalCheck string will be like this "'Jurufoto','Hiburan'"

and when you concatinate it with the query like this

```
AND vendor.type IN ('%". $finalCheck ." %')" );
```

it become like this

```
 AND vendor.type IN ('%'Jurufoto','Hiburan' %')" );
```

which is wrong sql statement eather you have to change like this

```
 AND vendor.type IN (". $finalCheck .")" );
```

OR if you want to check with like then you have to see this thread

[MySQL IN with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732246/mysql-in-with-like)

And make sure to print the `$sql` before fetching data and match it with your desired output

Now your code will be like this

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h3><label for="usr">Carian bajet anda:</label></h3>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class=" col-md-4"></div>

            <div class=" col-md-4">
                <input name="bajet" type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <h3><label for="sel1">Pilih negeri pilihan anda:</label></h3>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class=" col-md-4"></div>
        <div class=" col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="sel">
                <option>Kuala Lumpur</option>
                <option>Negeri Sembilan</option>
                <option>Pahang</option>
                <option>Perak</option>
                <option>Terengganu</option>
                <option>Selangor</option>

            </select>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <br>


    <br>
    <h5><label for="check">Senarai Pra-perkahwinan:</label></h5>
    <center>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"
                                                   value="Jurufoto"><label>Jurufoto</label></label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"
                                                   value="Butik"><label>Butik</label></label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"
                                                   value="Hiburan"><label>Hiburan</label></label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Kad Kahwin"><label>Kad
                    Kahwin</label></label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"
                                                   value="Katering"><label>Katering</label></label>
            <br>
        </div>
    </center>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="search">Search&nbsp;<span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4"></div>

</form>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Jenis</th>
        <th>Vendor</th>
        <th>Negeri</th>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Pakej</th>
        <th>Harga</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $check = array();
        $budget = $_POST['bajet'];
        $select = $_POST['sel'];
        $check = implode("','", $_POST['check_list']);
        $finalCheck = "'" . $check . "'";
        $check = array();

        mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);

        $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT *
                 FROM vendor
                    RIGHT JOIN item
                      ON vendor.v_id=item.v_id
                        WHERE item.harga <= '%" . $budget . "%'
                          AND vendor.state = '%" . $select . "%'
                            AND vendor.type IN (" . $finalCheck . ")");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['companyName'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['contact'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['harga'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pakej'] ?></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?v_id=<?php echo $row['v_id'] ?>">View Package</a></td>


            </tr>

        <?php }
    }
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Don't use mysql connection because the mysql_* functions has been deprecated as of 5.5.0. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** for the database connectivity.

Comment: this one is correct and elaboration is done perfectly. +10

Comment: so you suggesting my like is the one that make problem?and i already tried the AND vendor.type IN (". $finalCheck .")" ); but stll got warning implode() invalid argument passed :(..btw nice explaination

Comment: Check the value before imploding by printing `$_POST['check_list']` like this `print_r($_POST['check_list'])`.
Make sure it is an array

Comment: Array ( [0] => Butik [1] => Kad Kahwin )

Comment: surround your php code by `if(isset($_POST['search']))` and check it

Comment: hey i tried your coding..it contain no error but the table remain blank?:(

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$check = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);
```

Comment: @Anant: OP said it didn't work. Did it work for you?

Comment: I want to say that this one will be one more correct step to proceed.

Comment: @Anant This answer is the same as what the OP has already tried. Probably the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already added single quote at the time of creation $finalCheck, so no need to add single quote again in clause.

```
$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * 
             FROM vendor 
                RIGHT JOIN item 
                  ON vendor.v_id=item.v_id
                    WHERE item.harga <= '%". $budget . "%' 
                      AND vendor.state = '%". $select ."%'
                        AND vendor.type IN (%". $finalCheck ." %)" );
```

Comment: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: There is no error in this line : $check = implode("','", $_POST['check_list']); But put it after check it's value. like : if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) { $check = implode("','", $_POST['check_list']);}

Comment: after i replacemy with yours ,now my problem is  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 126 which is  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { after i filled all the form and click search.

Comment: please echo $sql or just update that line:  $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT *
                 FROM vendor
                    RIGHT JOIN item
                      ON vendor.v_id=item.v_id
                        WHERE item.harga <= '%" . $budget . "%'
                          AND vendor.state = '%" . $select . "%'
                            AND vendor.type IN (" . $finalCheck . ")") or die(mysql_error());